# select multiple items in a listview and change background color of selected item

Tags: android, android-listview

Hey I am stuck with 1 thing that I want a view like this :

[image]

where in a listview I can select multiple items and whichever item I can select I can change the backgrond color and also add that item into the arraylist so that I can use it further..

Anyone please help me in this??

**EDIT:**

Am using it like this:

```
     ArrayAdapter<String> part_list_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(AssetSearch.this,  R.layout.part_list,R.id.label,part_array_list);

    PartNumber_List.setAdapter(part_list_adapter);


       PartNumber_List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        String item = (String)PartNumber_List.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Log.i("Item", item);
         v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.result_image_border);

    }
});
```

Here in a  log it is displaying me the item clicked only..but changes color of 2 items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

```
  @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Get the item that was clicked
   String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    boolean blnFound = yourarrayList.contains(item);
 if(blnFound=true){
     yourarraylist.remove(item);
       v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.somecolourtoindicate notselected);

    }
   else{
          yourarraylist.add(item);
          v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.somecolourtoindicate itemselected);
    }
    yourarraylist.add((String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);)
}
```

Comment: But here still am getting a problem that when I am selecting a single item from listview, then it automatically select another..Means when I am clicking on 1 item, it automactically changes color of 2

Comment: I am clue less.. why colour of 2 fields is changing.. when only one item is being displayed

Comment: Hey I finally got the solution..Thanks fro your support :)

Comment: @Kanika can u give complete code of how you managed to do it?

Comment: While this may seem to work at frst, once you select then unselect a row, you cannot select it again.

Answer (score 1):

Your going to set Background for View v of list view cell, actually list view adapter reuse the cell view when you scroll the view, because of that the color reflect in some other rows cell.

Only option you need to add one image view to the View holder and try to change the background of image view in view holder , don`t change adapter view color.

Comment: Can you please give me some hint that how to implement it.. Am stuck here from yesterday and didnt get any solution yet :(

Comment: you need to use custom adapter for that instead of Default array adapter.

Comment: pls check my updated 2nd question on stackoverflow..am really confused with this and trying alot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100324/select-multiple-items-from-listview-and-change-color-of-selected-item-only/10100512#10100512

Comment: @Kanika   can u pls show u resolved your issue i m also  facing same issue