# Select multiple items from listview and change color of selected item only

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make a view where I can select multiple items from listview and also side by side am changing the color of selected list item and saving that item into my arraylist..My list is shown as below as:

[image]

But when I used to scroll it.. It is showing me 1 more item selected, even I am not selecting it like:

[image]

But I want that only that list item color should change where I will click...

I am using the code as:

```
     private class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 List<String> items;
  Context context;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<String> part_array_list) {
     super( context, R.layout.part_list, R.id.label,part_array_list );

     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      TextView textView ; 
    String item = (String) this.getItem( position ); 

      if ( convertView == null ) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.part_list, null);

        // Find the child views.
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.label );


        // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have to 
        // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row.
        convertView.setTag( new ListViewHolder(textView) );


      }
      // Reuse existing row view
      else {
        // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call findViewById().
        ListViewHolder viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        textView = viewHolder.getTextView() ;

      }


      textView.setText( part_array_list.get(position) );      

      return convertView;


      }
      }
        /** Holds child views for one row. */
           private class ListViewHolder {

 private TextView textView ;
 public ListViewHolder() {}
 public ListViewHolder( TextView textView ) {

   this.textView = textView ;
 }

 public TextView getTextView() {
   return textView;
 }
 public void setTextView(TextView textView) {
   this.textView = textView;
 }
```

}

and in OnCreate() method,

```
         final ArrayAdapter<String> part_list_adapter=new ItemsAdapter(AssetSearch.this, part_array_list);
        //PartNumber_List.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    PartNumber_List.setAdapter(part_list_adapter);

    PartNumber_List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
         ListViewHolder viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) v.getTag();
         viewHolder.getTextView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.result_image_border);

        String item=(String) part_list_adapter.getItem((int) id);
        });
```

Comment: This is because in Android list gets recycled when you scroll the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is that you are setting the background color to the view, then when you scroll, you end up reusing that view due to using `convertView`. This is exactly what you should be doing, so good job there.

But, of course, that means list items are selected when they shouldn't be. In order to fix this, your `getView()` method needs to reset the background color to its default value. I don't know what the color was originally, but I'll assume it was transparent. So you would put:

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

So now you're setting the background color to its default, but if you scroll away from the selected item, then back to it, it will have a transparent background instead of the selected background. To resolve this, put an `ArrayList` of `Integer` values inside your adapter class. When an item is clicked and `onItemClick()` is triggered, add the item position to that `ArrayList`. For example, say you have:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

in your adapter class. Then, your `onItemClick` method would look like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

     ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = ((ItemsAdapter) parent).selectedIds;
     Integer pos = new Integer(position);
     if(selectedIds.contains(pos) {
         selectedIds.remove(pos);
     }
     else {
         selectedIds.add(pos);
     }

     parent.notifyDataChanged();
}
```

So, finally, in your `getView()` method, add this line:

```
textView.setBackground(selectedIds.contains(position) ? R.color.result_image_border : androi.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your anwer but when I am adding public ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>(); in my adapter class, then in onlistItemClick, it is not taking ((ItemsAdapter) parent).selectedIds; it is giving me an error here and does not extract selectedIds variable from adapter class :( pls help what to do

Comment: You need the `ArrayList` in the adapter, and then access it from the `onItemClick` method in the activity. You can choose whatever means you want to do this, it doesn't have to be what I wrote verbatim. I'd recommend using a getter method.

Comment: Hey pls resolve this problem.. Am not able to..AM not getting that how an arraylist should communicate between OnItemClick  method and arrayaspater?? If I did created an arraylist in adapter class , then I am not able to get it in OnItemClick method?? pls help :(

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your suport.. Finally I got the solution :)

Comment: @Kanika How did you solve it in the end? i'm getting same error and can't figure out the problem for some reason it tells me Cannot cast from AdapterView<capture#1-of ?> to my class

Comment: @Kanika Hey i also got same error that "Cannot cast from AdapterView<capture#1-of ?> to "..and can't figure out.so plz tell me how u got solution.. plz help.. :(

Comment: @Kanika I put ArrayList in the adapter and tried to access it from the onItemClick in activity class. But still showing "Cannot cast from AdapterView<capture#1-of ?>myAdapter". Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered this problem, and found out that it is because recycling views. If i remember right setting this removes recycling and fixes the problem, but it's not the best option here.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
}
```

Comment: You override this method for the adapter class.

Comment: Add also this : @Override
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
  return 1;
 }

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the items selected in the listView in the Activity. In the getView of the adapter check if position equals selected position in the listview and setBackgroundColor for the view there. This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you try to do with ConvertView in itemClick listener it will reflect in some other class, to avoid that you need to set the background for corresponding view holder , i show up some sample which works fine for me,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         System.gc();
         final ViewHolder holder;

         if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.albumlist, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
             holder.albumName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.albumDetails);

             convertView.setTag(holder);
         }
         else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }


         holder.albumName.setText(albumData[position][0]);

         holder.albumName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 holder.albumName.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);


             }});

         return convertView;
 }

     class ViewHolder {

         TextView albumName;


     }
```

sample o/p
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set flag when you click any list item from the list and check this flag to determine weather the item has been clicked or not in you getView() method of the adapter.

Comment: pls help how to implement this.. I am stuck in this problem from yesterday and didnt get any solution yet :(

Answer (score 0):

A correction about the answer given by @JasonRobinson:

```
if(selectedIds.contains(pos) {
         selectedIds.remove(pos); -> **selectedIds.remove(selectedIds.indexOf(pos));**
     }
     else {
         selectedIds.add(pos);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution (idea) from **Jason Robinson** is good, but there is an error! You can not remove item from ArrayList by it's value!!!
Method ArrayList.remove(int) takes item's index as parametr!
If you want to use an `ArrayList<Integer>`, you need to find index ot item you want to remove. For example:

```
private int getIndex(int value) {
    int index = -1;

    for(int i=0; i<selectedIds.size(); i++) {
        if(selectedIds.get(i)==value) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

Or use method `ArrayList.indexOf(Object)` to obtain index.
And now, how to get reference to your adapter from FragmenList or ListActivity. Simply use class variable:

```
public class SimpleFragment extends ListFragment {
    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_layout);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // now you have an access to your adapter through class variable mAdapter
    }
}
```

Comment: Another solution to the first issue you mentioned is to use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList.  HashSet.remove() takes the object in question rather than an index: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object)