# How to inflate a layout which itself contains a linearlayout in itself?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, custom-adapter

I'm making a custom adapter. The list_item of my `ListView` is having a `LinearLayout` in itself, in which I'm adding `ImageView`s later on.
I'm using the following code:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row_Item> {
    private java.util.List<Row_Item> List;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Row_Item> list, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.row_item, list);
        this.List = list;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return List.size();
    }

    public Row_Item getItem(int position) {
        return List.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return List.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        TopicHolder holder = new TopicHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            *LinearLayout* l = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

            holder.topic = tv;
            holder.myLayout = l;
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (TopicHolder) v.getTag();
        Row_Item p = List.get(position);
        holder.topic.setText(p.getName());
        ImageView imgUsers;
        for (int i = 0; i < some_parameter; i++) {                  imgUsers = new ImageView(context);
                    imgUsers.setImageResource(some_image);
                    holder.myLayout.addView(imgUsers); //add that image to my linearlayout
                } 
        return v;
    }

    private static class TopicHolder {
        public TextView topic;
        public LinearLayout myLayout;
        // public ImageView notifications;
    }
}
```

So what happens here is the `getView()` is called infinitely. Also, I have set `onItemClickListener` in the class from where this adapter is called. As the adapter class doesn't terminate, the listener doesn't work and app remains stand still.

Also, I had tried things like `myLayout.getChildCount()` and returning if it is greater than the number of images but still the infinite loop doesn't terminate.

Comment: no need to call super for custom adapter

Comment: wat is the need of the for loop inside getView?Do you need to set multiple images in a single list item? or only one image per list item ?If only one image is required,you need to remove that for loop inside getView..

Comment: getView will be called based on how many items are there in your List. That is the could returned from getCount(). It wont be called infinitely. What is some_parameter here?

Comment: please go threw some good  custom list view tutorial there is many good tutorial on the net for that

Comment: @amj Yes, I am inserting multiple images. That is done by myLinearLayout.addView(imgUsers)

Comment: @prijupaul some_parameter is exactly the number of images to be added in a specific list_item or the number of images added in the myLayout for a specific list_item. Also, it inserts exactly the same number of items as are there in the List when it runs for the first time. But when we scroll or do any action in the listView, it goes on adding the same images(some_parameter number of images) for infinite times.

Comment: @anddevmanu If I don't call super, I get an error "Implicit super constructor ArrayAdapter<Row_Item>() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor" And if you find any tutorial having a LinearLayout inside individual ListItem of ListView, share the link here.

Comment: I got the solution. I set the onClickListener in the adapter itself and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
        View v = convertView;

```
    TopicHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        holder = new TopicHolder();

        holder.topic = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        holder.myLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (TopicHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    Row_Item p = List.get(position);
    holder.topic.setText(p.getName());
    ImageView imgUsers;
            Log.e("some_param",some_parameter+"");
    for (int i = 0; i < some_parameter; i++) {
        imgUsers = new ImageView(context);
                 Log.e("some_param",some_image+"   "+i);
        imgUsers.setImageResource(some_image);
        holder.myLayout.addView(imgUsers);
    }
    return v;
}
```

If still getview not working then please debug innerloop in getview for adding images in linearlayout.

initialize some_parameter value default 0.

Comment: No, it still doesn't make any difference. And I have imposed all the constraints on the innerloop, even I have written the statement "return v" in case myLayout.getChildCount() >= some_parameter. But still it works the same.

Comment: The answer in this question relates pretty much here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100324/select-multiple-items-from-listview-and-change-color-of-selected-item-only

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. I set the onClickListener in the adapter itself and it works fine.

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row_Item> {
    private java.util.List<Row_Item> List;
    private Context context;

    public Adapter(List<Row_Item> list, Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.row_item, list);
        this.List = list;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return List.size();
    }

    public Row_Item getItem(int position) {
        return List.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return List.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        TopicHolder holder = new TopicHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            *LinearLayout* l = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.myLayout);

            holder.topic = tv;
            holder.myLayout = l;
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (TopicHolder) v.getTag();
        Row_Item p = List.get(position);
        holder.topic.setText(p.getName());
        ImageView imgUsers;
        for (int i = 0; i < some_parameter; i++) {                  imgUsers = new ImageView(context);
                    imgUsers.setImageResource(some_image);
                    holder.myLayout.addView(imgUsers); //add that image to my linearlayout

        OnClickListener click= new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //do something (which I wasn't able to do earlier)
                }
            };
            v.setOnClickListener(click);
}
        return v;
    }

    private static class TopicHolder {
        public TextView topic;
        public LinearLayout myLayout;
        // public ImageView notifications;
    }
}
```

Comment: But still the question remains why does it go into an infinte loop and doesn't terminate of its own?

Comment: The answer in this question relates pretty much here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100324/select-multiple-items-from-listview-and-change-color-of-selected-item-only