# How to change background color in multiple items row delete in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am selecting multiple item in listview for delete . I can delete multiple item . The code is as follows :

```
smsListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                        int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                    // Capture total checked items
                    final int checkedCount = smsListView.getCheckedItemCount();
                    // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
                    mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
                    View v = smsListView.getChildAt(position
                            - smsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
                    ((SmsArrayAdapter) arrayAdapter).toggleSelection(position,v);

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
                        // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                        SparseBooleanArray selected = ((SmsArrayAdapter) arrayAdapter)
                                .getSelectedIds();
                        // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                        for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                                SMSItem selecteditem = (SMSItem) arrayAdapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                                // Remove selected items following the ids
                                arrayAdapter.remove(selecteditem);
                            }
                        }
                        // Close CAB
                        mode.finish();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ((SmsArrayAdapter) arrayAdapter).removeSelection();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }


            });
```

But I want to change color of the rows that I have selected . Currently there are no color on selection item in the list .

[image]

I have tried the following .

Step no 1: write below line to to your listview item layout

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

Step no 2: write below line to style.xml file

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/muliple_selected_item</item>
 </style>
```

Step no 3: Create muliple_selected_item.xml into Drawable folder and write below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/lvMultipleSelectionColor" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/lvMultipleSelectionColor" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lvMultipleSelectionColor" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

But by this code , all itemsof the list are colored when I select any item of the listview . I want to change background color to those items only which I have selected . 
How can I do this ?

The listview layoput is as follows  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/smsItemContainerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:text="SMS Inbox"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unread_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/notification_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="88"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"   
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="invisible" />



    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/SMSList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"  />


</LinearLayout>
```

The rows layout is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/muliple_selected_item" >>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SMS From"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_sms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="SMS : "  />

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Time : "  />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The muliple_selected_item.xml is as follows : .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/lvMultipleSelectionColor" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/lvMultipleSelectionColor" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lvMultipleSelectionColor" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I am following this link .http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/

Comment: can u post your xml?

Comment: Which xml I have to post ?

Comment: xml that contains ListView

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447238/how-to-change-background-color-of-selected-items-in-listview

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085666/select-multiple-items-in-a-listview-and-change-background-color-of-selected-item

Comment: @osimer did u find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Multiple Select Choice mode to your `ListView`

```
smsListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

You need to create Drawable file for your `ListView's` row Layout and use `Drawable` as background in that layout.

Here is Drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/menuitem_press_background_color" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

**EDIT:**

remove `changeBackgroundColor()` used in `selectView()` and check if it works

You can refer this [Selecting multiple items in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362602/selecting-multiple-items-in-listview). it might help you

Comment: I have done it . But no change in rows background color is noticed .

Comment: pls post your listview layout and listview row layout

Comment: show muliple_selected_item file and also set  android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" to your Listview in xml and programatically also as mentioned in answer

Comment: have you set choicemode in xml and in java file

Comment: Yes I have set choicemode in xml and java file . I can select multiple item of listview . The only problem I am facing is no background color is noticed in selected item .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91546/discussion-between-osimer-pothe-and-rajesh-jadav).

Answer (score 2):

Just put the line below in your single row xml file(the xml file in which you define the define the layout for single row of listview):-

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

And no need to edit any more xml files. For more details, please visit the link below :-

[Click here to go to link ...!](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It works, it changes the color, but in my case it changes the color to black and I can't see the view, how to define a specific color in it without affecting initial items color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawables for that like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_activated="true"
android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</selector>
```

and set it as background of your row layout,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_background_activated" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have done it . But no change in rows background color is noticed .

Answer (score 0):

> You can Achieve it in this way:-
>
> 1. First add property(variable) isSelected to SMSItem class with default Value false.
> 2. on onItemCheckedStateChanged method Execution set value for variable isSelected.
> 3. on getView method of Adapter you have to chech value for isSelected  variable. then make a decison base on it, if false then set default
>      background and if true the set another background to perticular row.
> 4. call notifyDataSetChanged() method on Adepter from onItemCheckedStateChanged.
>
> on Your Request, Im posting Code:-
>
> add this to onItemCheckedStateChanged method

```
SMSItem selecteditem = (SMSItem) arrayAdapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
selecteditem.setSelection(checked);
notifydatasetChanged();
```

> and manage getView yourself